# Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.date.time' and 'char'

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I received this error on following code.Is this + sign is not available in C# ?

Error : Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.date.time' and 'char'

```
 return StartDate +';'+EndDate;
```

EDIT :

After the answers i edited code like this.but then i got those error

```
return StartDate.ToString() + ';' + EndDate.ToString();
```

Error : Since Hdate.HDate(); return void,a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

The Whole Code is here :[Click Here to see whole code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094587/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-string-to-system-date-time-but-declare-in-datetim/11094671#11094671)

Comment: What are you trying to return exactly? At the moment you are trying to return two values. You can only return one.

Comment: I very much doubt that the error you've given is exactly the one the compiler is reporting. There's no such type as "System.date.time". Always copy and paste error messages directly.

Comment: Are you returning something for a method which says `void` as its return type ? then you will have to make that as `string`

Comment: @V4Vendetta I'm not returning void.. please check the code before edited here.Please see the whole code in the final part of the post

Comment: What you have in the posted code is a return in the constructor which is not supported, maybe you could have a property which concatenates them and return them.

Comment: BTW: why are you using two accounts (Chathura nad Learner) here?

Comment: No.this is our university lab.we are nearby

Comment: we are altogether doing our assignment.When we have a trouble we search everywhere if so.. we cant figureout then we post to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use ";" instead of ';':

```
return StartDate +";"+EndDate;
```

There is a + operator for strings (Concat) and it will operate on objects (with .ToString()) - so the statement is valid if you give a string.
In your case there is none such operator for characters and the compiler cannot know that you implicitly want to convert everything to string.

EDIT: to your second problem (consider making it a new question in the future):

straight from your code (full version):

```
public HDate(){

    DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
    /* snip - not relevant */   
       return StartDate+';'+EndDate;
   }
```

you see: this is a constructor for your `HDate` type - and you return something in the last statment ... but you MUST not

Comment: it's about the fact that adding a string to something makes it `ToString()` by default, it doesn't work that way with a char.

Comment: I don't think it was unclear as it is a solution to the problem but I did elaborate...

Comment: I don't find the place in the linked question but I guess you are trying to return something from your constructor.... DON'T

Comment: oh yes you do ... see my edit - and please forgive me but this is **very** basic stuff and I guess you have to invest some time to learn those fundamental things - it will be a mess to ask for each syntax error you will get

Comment: @CarstenKönig Just look before that code i put a Constructor there know? did you see ? Look this coding  [link](http://postimage.org/image/hq3ubru6v/b79d1cc3/)

Comment: the problem is not your first constructor - it's the fact that you try to return a string from the second constructor (the one you did not circle) ... I will stop this conversation here as it will not yield any results - try to understand what a constructor is and rethink your code - cannot say more

Comment: ok.thank you for your instructions.I'm a fresher to C#.thats whay this type of silly mistakes happend

Comment: i read constructor tuitorial & solve it.. return type added to constructor

Answer (score 2):

The problem is when literal value is enclosed in single quotes, it is `char`, not `string`. You could use double quotes then it should work, or use `String.Format()`:

```
    return String.Format("{0};{1}", StartDate, EndDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your trying to return a string then you need

```
return StartDate.ToString() +';'+EndDate.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return String.Format(
                 CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
                 "{0};{1}", 
                 StartDate,  
                 EndDate);
```

Comment: Supplying `CurrentCulture` is totally redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return it as string so convert StartDate and EndDate to String. For formating using .ToString method for DateTime refer [Here](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm)

Answer (score 0):

something wrong in your code.do like this.

```
return StartDate.ToString() + ';' + EndDate.ToString();
```

Simply use .ToString();

Is you return something but in void case ?