# How to initialize a DateTime field?

Tags: c#, datetime

I am absolutly new in C# (I came from Java) and I have a very stupid problem

I have to initialize some **DateTime** fields into an object but I have some problems doing it.

In particular I am trying to inizialize these fields in this way:

```
mySmallVuln.Published = '1998,04,30';
mySmallVuln.LastUpdated = '2007,11,05';
```

But Visual Studio sign me it as error

> Too many characters in character literal

What am I missing? How to solve it?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
mySmallVuln.Published = new DateTime(1998,04,30);
```

Or perhaps like this

```
var date = DateTime.MinValue;
if (DateTime.TryParse("1998/04/30", out date))
{
    //Sucess...
    mySmallVuln.Published = date;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

```
 DateTime d = default(DateTime);
```

The default keyword works for all data types too!

Answer (score 9):

Both are same....

**1**

```
mySmallVuln.Published = new DateTime(1998,04,30,0,0,0);
mySmallVuln.LastUpdated = new DateTime(2007,11,05,0,0,0);
```

**2**

```
mySmallVuln.Published = new DateTime(1998,04,30);
mySmallVuln.LastUpdated = new DateTime(2007,11,05);
```

in the first method you can assign hour minute and second respectively in parameter at the last three parameter.

Answer (score 4):

To initialize a `DateTime` value you can use the `DateTime` constructor:

```
mySmallVuln.Published = new DateTime(1998,04,30);
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using a character literal `''` which can only contain one character. If you want to use a string literal use `""` instead.

C# does not support `DateTime`-literals as opposed to [VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3eaydw6e.aspx) (`#4/30/1998#`).

Apart from that, a string is not a `DateTime`. If you have a string you need to parse it to `DateTime` first:

```
string published = "1998,04,30";
DateTime dtPublished = DateTime.ParseExact(published, "yyyy,MM,dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
mySmallVuln.Published = dtPublished;
```

or you can create a `DateTime` via constructor:

```
DateTime dtPublished = new DateTime(1998, 04, 30);
```

or, since your string contains the year, month and day as strings, using `String.Split` and `int.Parse`:

```
string[] tokens = published.Split(',');
if (tokens.Length == 3 && tokens.All(t => t.All(Char.IsDigit)))
{
    int year = int.Parse(tokens[0]);
    int month = int.Parse(tokens[1]);
    int day = int.Parse(tokens[2]);
    dtPublished = new DateTime(year, month, day);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, C# does not support Date literals. You should change your code and instantiate the DateTime objects using `new DateTime(..)`, as thomas exemplified in his answer.

Just for the sake of expanding on this topic: VB.NET supports date literals using the # character (ironically). This is how they can be expressed, from the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711653%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
Dim d As Date
d = # 8/23/1970 3:45:39AM #
d = # 8/23/1970 #              ' Date value: 8/23/1970 12:00:00AM.
d = # 3:45:39AM #              ' Date value: 1/1/1 3:45:39AM.
d = # 3:45:39 #                ' Date value: 1/1/1 3:45:39AM.
d = # 13:45:39 #               ' Date value: 1/1/1 1:45:39PM.
d = # 1AM #                    ' Date value: 1/1/1 1:00:00AM.
d = # 13:45:39PM #             ' This date value is not valid.
```

Answer (score 3):

If you search for the error you get, you'll [find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606664/getting-a-too-many-characters-in-charater-literal-error-please-help):

> This is because, in C#, single quotes ('') denote (or encapsulate) a single character, whereas double quotes ("") are used for a string of characters.

So you'll try:

```
DateTime foo = "2014,02,20";
```

Which yields:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'

Now if you search for *that* error, you'll [find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094587/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-string-to-system-date-time-but-declare-in-datetim):

```
int StartYear = 2012;
int StartMonth = 06;
int StartDay = 15;

DateTime dt = new DateTime(StartYear, StartMonth, StartDay);
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

// year,month,day

```
mySmallVuln.Published=new DateTime(2011,11,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either parse a string, like yours. Or you can instansiate a DateTime object with numbers.

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(1998, 04, 30);
DateTime date2 = DateTime.ParseExact("1998,04,30", "yyyy,MM,dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```