# Convert a specific format dateTime string to DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have a formatted datetime string and I want to convert it back to DateTime but when I parse or convert that string to DateTime it throws exceptio that string is not a valid dateTime.

Here is how DateTime string is created

```
string temp = dt.Year.ToString("D4") + 
              dt.Month.ToString("D2") + 
              dt.Day.ToString("D2") + 
              dt.Hour.ToString("D2") + 
              dt.Minute.ToString("D2") + 
              dt.Second.ToString("D2");
```

and here is how i am parsing it back to DateTime

```
 DateTime dtchk = DateTime.Parse(temp);
```

Comment: Looks like your `dt` _already_ a `DateTime`? Why don't you use it instead? What is your `temp` looks like when you debug your code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse string to DateTime in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366285/parse-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Yes it is but this is happening in a different module...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906935/how-to-initialize-a-datetime-field/21906992#21906992

Comment: check this :https://dotnetfiddle.net/Uy6TJa

Comment: (OT) you could also use `string temp = dt.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");` to create that string. Which is also the format you need to parse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Yes it is but this is happening in a different module.

I don't *even* understand what is that mean. I think you just need;

```
DateTime dtchk = dt;
```

Nothing more. But anyway.. I try to explain;

Since [`"D"` format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#DFormatString) generates string representation with leading zeros if your string length is less than precision specifier, your `temp` will be the combination of these wider formats of months, day, hour etc..

And `DateTime.Parse` parses your string successfully if this string is a [standard date and time format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) of your [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In your case, it is not.

You need to parse your string with [`ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to specify your formats exactly.

```
DateTime dtchk = DateTime.ParseExact(temp, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", null);
```