# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime server error

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, datetimeoffset, datetime-parsing

Below is my code

```
var result =
    (from SV in Tbl
     where (DateTimeOffset.Parse(SV.FieldName) >= DateTimeOffset.Parse(StartDate) 
     && DateTimeOffset.Parse(SV.FieldName) <= DateTimeOffset.Parse(EndDate))
     group SV by 1 into SVgrp
     select new { Count = SVgrp.Sum(p => p.Count) }).ToList()
```

The value of `SV.FieldName = '19-06-2015'`, `StartDate = '2015-09-20T00:00:00Z'`, `EndDate = '2015-10-21T23:59:59Z'`

On my development machine, this code works perfectly whereas on my server, its giving me error `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`

Both my machines have date format set as English(India), Location as India and Timezone set as UTC.

I tried adding `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` on all four Parse methods, but the error did not go.

Why am I getting this error on server only? How can it be solved?

Comment: have you tried using `DateTime.ParseExact`? You can specify there format of datetime

Comment: You can Try this    `DateTime.Parse(StartDate.Value.Trim()).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: @wudzik I havent used ParseExact, I will try that, but then why isnt it giving me error on my development machine?

Comment: @Hitesh different DateTime format defined in system

Comment: @AnshulChoure I cannot convert my date to string as I am comparing them

Comment: Check the answer from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906935/how-to-initialize-a-datetime-field/21906992#21906992

Comment: @thomas I cannot use tryparse as I want to parse each and every datefield and compare it with Start and EndDate within my Linq query

Answer (score 1):

I'm certain that the error comes when converting the value of s.FieldName = '19-06-2015'. The compiler assume that the format is MM-dd-yyyy and therefor 19 is seen as an invalid month number.

my suggestion will be to construct the date value, see below

```
    var result = (from SV in Tbl
           where (new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(SV.FieldName.Substring(6, 4)), Convert.ToInt32(SV.FieldName.Substring(3, 2)), Convert.ToInt32(SV.FieldName.Substring(0, 2))) >= DateTimeOffset.Parse(StartDate) 
           && new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(SV.FieldName.Substring(6, 4)), Convert.ToInt32(SV.FieldName.Substring(3, 2)), Convert.ToInt32(SV.FieldName.Substring(0, 2))) <= DateTimeOffset.Parse(EndDate))
           group SV by 1 into SVgrp
           select new { Count = SVgrp.Sum(p => p.Count) }).ToList()
```

this is not the best but it will do the job.

Comment: This does the job, it does not gives error any more, thanks. however this is not the best solution I would like to have on my production, but it has given me inroads, I will improvise on it, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, @"d/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

or

DateTime.TryParse(dateString,out date4);

if the parsing fails, it will not throw error, rather it returns false indicating that the parsing failed.