# Is there a short-hand to initialize a DateTime variable?

Tags: c#, syntax

Is there a short-hand to initialize a DateTime variable in C#, without explicitly declaring a new object? For example, in VB.NET, you can surround a string value in hashes.

```
Dim date1 As Date = #5/1/2008 8:30:52AM#
```

Comment: you still have to declare the variable....

Comment: What are you looking to create if not a `DateTime` object?  What specific result are you trying to achieve and why does it need to be "shorter"?  Note that, if you're measuring by keystrokes alone, the VB example you gave is *longer*.  It's also worth noting that these two operations produce different results.  So it's not really clear what exactly you're asking.

Comment: DateTime != string in terms of declaration - initializing the object properties is required.

Comment: Just use Parse DateTime.Parse("6/9/2019") but order is defendant on month or day being first.  You could use international standard : DateTime.Parse("2019-05-20").

Comment: @jdweng Probably a good idea to use `ParseExact` and provide a format and, perhaps, a CultureInfo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize a DateTime field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906935/how-to-initialize-a-datetime-field)

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a better or faster what than to actually create a `DateTime` object using the `new` operator.

You *can* use the `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime ParseExact` methods (or the `Try*` versions of these) to create a `DateTime` object for you but this adds some unnecessary overhead such as for example allocating a `string`:

```
var d = DateTime.Parse("5/1/2008 8:30:52AM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

By assigning the DateTime object a date and time value returned by a property or method. 
The following example assigns the current date and time, the current Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) date and time, and the current date to three new DateTime variables.

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime date2 = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime date3 = DateTime.Today;
```

Or if you need to parse a string to a DateTime, you could use this:

```
string iDate = "05/05/2005";
DateTime oDate = DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(iDate, "M/d/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
MessageBox.Show(oDate.Day + " " + oDate.Month + "  " + oDate.Year );
```

I hope this is something you are looking for?

Comment: You should not use `Convert.ToDateTime` to convert a string to a `DateTime`. Use `DateTime.ParseExact` or one of the other derivatives.

Comment: Then you are only using one format.  The standard Net Library will automatically parse a wide range of formats.  You should only use Exact if the data is not one of the standard formats that Net uses.

Comment: @jdweng: Doing that relies on the host machine's culture info, leading to potential runtime problems in different environments.  (And not always an error, but perhaps silently parsing an incorrect result.)  More to the point though... Why parse a string literal at all?  If it's already hard-coded then just use hard-coded values to construct a `DateTime` explicitly and skip all this string parsing.