# Convert DateTime Format 04-08-2021 00:00:00 to string '08/04/2021' in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to convert Datetime format 04-08-2021 00:00:00 to string "08/04/2021"(MM/dd/YYYY) format but when I tried this code I am getting following error

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        String[] Arr = new String[4];
        DateTime Date1=04-08-2021 00:00:00
        Arr[0]=Date1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Console.WriteLine(Arr[0]);
    }
}
```

Error

```
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
main.cs(10,35): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `0'
```

Comment: You cannot declare a datetime like that. You have to parse the string and construct the object.

Comment: `04-08-2021 00:00:00`  is unkown to C#. You either have to declare it as a string `"04-08-2021 00:00:00"` and then parse it, or declare like `new DateTime(2021,8,4)`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906935/how-to-initialize-a-datetime-field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot declare a `DateTime` as such a literal. You have to parse it as a string:

```
DateTime Date1 = DateTime.Parse("04-08-2021 00:00:00");
Console.WriteLine(Date1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

You have to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to ensure that the slashes are rendered, because otherwise your current date-separators are used which might be different. For example here in germany without this i get: `08.04.2021`. See [the "/" custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dateSeparator)
Another way to ensure it was to escape the format specifier with ticks around:

```
Date1.ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy")
```